Rank and Null Space of Nonlinear Transformation
Why can a nonlinear transformation not have a rank and a null space – specifically the following transformation:
$T:\mathbf{F_4}\rightarrow \mathbf{F_4}$ such that $T(x)=x^2$ where $\mathbf{F_4}$ is a 2-dimensional vector space over $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ with basis $\beta =\{1, X\}$. In other words, $\mathbf{F}_4=\{a+bX:a,b\in\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}\}$.
Any explanation would be much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Modulo $2$ the squaring map is linear, since $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \equiv a^2 + b^2$.
In general, you can't square elements of a vector space.

Thank you very much!

If a map between vector spaces is linear there's a matrix and we can talk about it's rank.
The so-called null space won't be a subspace at all in general for non-linear maps.
So things just don't work out.
You might want to look into real analysis and/or Banach or Hilbert spaces  wherethere are inner products and what not, as well as any number of other areas like dynamical systems, nonlinear analysis etc, etc.
For the category Vect of vector spaces the morphisms are linear maps.

While I didn't pay much attention to the specific transformation,  I don't appreciate the downvote,  chihuahua.
